# Typescript in VS2012: (automatically) generating .js from .ts

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I've added `file1.ts` and I can see there's a dependent to it - namely `file1.js`.

I notice that any changes I made to `file1.ts` - `file1.js` doesn't get automatically re-generated.

The only workaround I have at the moment is by calling `tsc.exe` - as part of pre-build event.

My question is - are there any better workaround or maybe a setting somewhere I might've missed ?

Comment: I'm asking this because it seems in the playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) - the .js file gets generated on the fly ! I feel a bit intimidated that the playground is kind of better than VS2012 :(

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Install the Web Essentials 2012 extension in Visual Studio 2012.

It will re-generate the .js file on every save of the .ts file.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Comment: But what about the CommonJS requires() stuff?  I'm not getting that in my compiled code and I have to include all the files myself.

Comment: @uosɐſ to compile your TS modules to AMD modules, you need to call the tsc compiler from a command prompt and pass the modules parameter: tsc --modules amd [list of filenames]

Comment: How do you get the same thing to work in VS 2012 web express?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't do it for me.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add a BeforeBuild target to your ASP.NET application's CSPROJ:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot;     @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

tip: edit your csproj file with notepad.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio Express you need to follow this step as Web Essentials is not supported for Express versions.

Comment: [TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790) is supported on Express and it includes a project type under C# called "HTML Application with TypeScript" which includes this in the CSPROJ by default.

Comment: For Typescript 0.8.1 refer to this: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/403394

Answer (score 4):

Support for typescript has been removed from Web Essentials 2012 v3

you now need to download typescript support directly from microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you need to invoke the build process for your files to be generated. The playground does not use the same build system, and it triggers the compilation once the source changes, so this is why you are seeing the difference in behavior.

Comment: note on this - the playground's probably using the `tsc.js` and as such can generate on the fly

Answer (score 0):

**plug**

You can use Install-Package TypeScript.Compile to add a afterbuild target that compiles all TypeScript files included in your project.